# Spring Cloud sleuth memory leak issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am facing issue with spring cloud sleuth as it is leaking memory as I have gone through the dumps of my applications:

What does 13.05mb (40.3%) of Java Static org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.SleuthContextListener.CACHE

Spring Cloud Version: Hoxton.SR8
Spring Boot Version: 2.3.3.RELEASE

Please find the heapdump report below:

https://heaphero.io/my-heap-report.jsp?p=YXJjaGl2ZWQvMjAyMS8wNS8yNS8tLWhlYXBkdW1wLTE2MjE5MjE0MzYyNTMuaHByb2YtNS00Ni0xLmpzb24=

[image]

pls find the code repo below, which I am using in my appplication, Also on first run there is no memory leakage issue but on successive runs it shows the memory leakage issue as mentioned in the heapdump report

```
   package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = { "config1", "config2" }, allEntries = true)
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000 * 5)
    public void cacheEvict() {
        log.info("Evicting all cache at: {}", new Date());
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-service</name>
    <description>demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ht</groupId>
            <artifactId>subscription-core-library</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>subscription-core-library-stg</id>
            <name>subscription-core-library-stg</name>
            <url>${repo.url}</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

TIA

Comment: That cache is a mapping around BeanFactory to a bean. How is it possible that you have 13 mb of BeanFactories?

Comment: I am using spring caching for caching resources . Maybe it is because of it?

Comment: I think issue is with the "@"enablecaching. Is there a way to use @enablecaching with spring cloud sleuth without memory leak?

Comment: You can enable caching - I don't understand why you have that many spring contexts

Comment: Problem is whenever I am using spring cloud sleuth dependecny with @enablecaching enable my heapdumps are showing my memory leak at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.ContextRefreshedListener.CACHE contain.

Comment: I understood that. I'm trying to understand why you have that many beanfactories loaded. Can you please create a small sample that replicates the problem? If you need to hack this around, you can create your own application listener in the `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.internal` package. Then you can call in your component SleuthContextListener.CACHE.clear();

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have tried to add the SleuthContextListener and ContextRefreshListener in my project but still it is giving me memory leak issue while trying to analyze my heapdump.

Comment: Added screenshot for the heapdump memory leak issue.

Comment: Like i said, i can only suggest some work arounds but the root cause is really that you have thay many application contexts. Thay is beyond my understanding. Please create a sample. They are more useful than screen shots. Also please upgrade to the latest version of the release train and the boot

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Added code snippets which I am using in my application along with the heapdump report, on normal projects it runs well for first few times but after 2 3 times it starts showing memory leakage issue with sleuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a complete mix of versions. Why do you say that you're using Hoxton and Boot 2.3 if you're not using Hoxton, you're using Greenwich and Boot 2.1

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Please upgrade to the latest version of Sleuth and Boot. Please replicate this issue by going to start.spring.io and generating a new, fresh project.

Update:

With the 2020.0.3 release I've changed one class that used to cache a bean factory in such a way that now it stores a hash of that class.

Comment: Because I have already tried with the latest version of spring boot, spring cloud sleuth and spring boot it is already giving the same memory leak issue.

Comment: Hi Marcin, As suggested by you I have tried with creating project from the start.spring.io and added the web and sleuth dependency in my project from the starter itself and after get the maven project into my ide I just added the @EnableCaching in my main() class. I got the heapdump and analyzed it on heaphero it is still giving me the same memory leak issue but with " org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.internal.SleuthContextListener object might be causing memory leak."
https://heaphero.io/my-heap-report.jsp?p=YXJjaGl2ZWQvMjAyMS8wNS8yNS8tLWhlYXBkdW1wLTE2MjE5MzQwMDkxOTAuaHByb2YtOS0xNC04Lmpzb24=

Comment: Above spring starter project has the following configuration:

Java Version: 1.8
Spring Boot Version: 2.5.0
Spring Cloud Version: 2020.0.3-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Please file an issue in spring-cloud-sleuth, attach the project and write steps to reproduce

Comment: Please wait 15 minutes and try again with the latest snaphosts (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1958)

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have taken the latest snapshot but still it showing the same old SleuthContextListener.java file not the updated one: static final Map<BeanFactory, SleuthContextListener> CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>

Comment: please build your project with `-U` flag -  `./mvnw clean install -U`

Comment: Thanks Marcin, Memory leak issue seems to be fixed in the new snapshot release, but is there any workaroud to do the same thing in the previous version of spring cloud which is stable version to use the same fix there. I am trying to override the Sleuthlistener class but it works normal initially but after sometimes starts giving memory leak issue. As most of the dependecies that we are using in our project spring boot version 2.4.5 and spring cloud version 2020.0.2 is not compatible with the latest snapshot release.

Comment: We should do the 2020.0.3 release tomorrow so that fix will end up there. I don't understand why it's a memory leak though? You have a gigantic bean factory and it just lays there in the cache. I'm not creating any new objects. I'm just caching existing ones.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, But I think issue is also replicating in the latest started project that I have created it is not just limited to my application.

Comment: Again, i don't think this is an issue at all